# Problemas para validar data inicial maior que final

Tags: jquery

Desenvolvi essa *function* para validar intervalo de datas, porém esta com uma falha que eu nao consigo resolver.

Se eu passo os valores:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deveria entrar na validação e não deixar salvar. Porém não acontece e eu não sei porquê.

```
    function ValidarDatas() {
        var dataInicial = $("#<%=txtDtIni.ClientID%>").val();
        var dataFinal = $("#<%=txtDtFim.ClientID%>").val();
        if (dataInicial > dataFinal) {
            criarDivAlert("Alerta", "Intervalo de datas inválidos");
            exibirAlerta(false);
            $("#<%=txtDtFim.ClientID%>").focus();
            cancelPostback = true;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está comparando textos e não datas, por isso a comparação não retorna o resultado esperado.

Criei uma função para converter o texto em data baseado na imagem que você colocou na sua pergunta, ou seja, a função espera receber uma data no formato dia/mes/ano.

Segue abaixo código funcionando:

```js
function ValidarDatas() {
    var data1 = $("#data1").val();
    var data2 = $("#data2").val();
    
    var dataInicial = ConverteParaData(data1);
    var dataFinal   = ConverteParaData(data2);
    
    
    if (dataInicial > dataFinal) {
        console.log("Data inválida!");
    }else{
        console.log("Data válida!");
    }
}

function ConverteParaData(data){
  var dataArray = data.split('/');
  var novaData = new Date(dataArray[2], dataArray[1], dataArray[0]);
  
  return novaData;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="data1" name="data1" value="31/12/2017" />
<input type="text" id="data2" name="data2" value="02/01/2018" />

<button type="button" id="validar" onclick="ValidarDatas()">
  Validar
</button>
```